# Excessive REFERENCES in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, reference

This is partly a best-practices question, partly a practical one:

I'm creating a new database table that will recast some old info (e.g. user_id/name, partner_application_id, etc.) alongside some new info (affiliate_id, transaction_id etc.). My inclination is to use Postgres `references` logic to do something like:

```
    create table transactions(
        transaction_id varchar(32) primary key,
        user_id serial references users(user_id),
        affiliate_id varchar(32) references affiliates(affiliate_id),
        partner_id varchar(32) references partners(partner_id),
        ...
        created_on date default now()
    );
```

My question is: Is this a proper/safe thing to do? It seems like this is a lot of references and I can't find any guidance online about whether this is ok or not. Maybe it'd make more sense to be less worried about references only in the sense that I wouldn't have to worry about inserting new users/affiliates into their respective tables first (as to deal with events that come in out of order due to asynchronicity)?

There are a lot of dependencies on other tables here, but ideally I would rather throw an error from not having a defined affiliate/user than have bad data going into the system and logging transactions for users who might not exist. Any rules of thumb or general guidelines here?

Comment: It is not impossible that a fact-table like this needs a handfull of references to "domain"-tables. When possible, I would try to avoid varchar(32) for PK/FK fields, and use (big)integer keys instead (these could be surrogate keys / serials) NB: both scenarios will assume stable keys for the referred tables.

Comment: The structure seems to be quite normal and correct, with the exception of primary keys, which in principle should be integer or bigint (as wildplasser has already noted). Of course, `user_id` cannot be `serial` here, but it's probably only a mistake.

Comment: @wilplasser - good to know, varchar(32) is essentially a hand-me-down from whoever created the tables that I'm referencing.

Comment: @klin: yeah I kinda sloppily threw this together, serial doesn't belong there haha

Comment: [I hadn't noticed the user_id serial references() ...] The problem with varchar(32) as FK->PK is that the indexes (*both* indexes) will be quite fat. If the varchar(32) is actually a natural key (such as a SSN or licence number) , it could just have a UNIQUE constraint in its domain table.

Comment: @wildplasser: I'm not sure I follow. Transaction Id's are unfortunately out of my control, and they come in the form a 30 char alphanumeric string.

Comment: If they are not under your control and this is **the only place** they are used in your model (*external* keys), keeping them as PK will not cause much trouble. Religious people would probably still prefer surrogate keys + a unique constraint. (see also: data-vault)